# Is a LCD backlight adjustable?

Tags: lcd

Wondering is LCD's backlight adjustable? If so, by making it dimer will the elements on the screen still be visible?

Thanks

Comment: It entirely depends on which LCD assembly you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stockstandard 2x16 LCD's I use have perfect readablility with no backlight. Sure, you'll need ambient light, but the green background is light enough to easily read the characters. Dimming the intensity of the backlight does not affect the blackness of the characters but simply adds a backlight that increases the readability of the characters in dim-lit environments.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. The reason I asked that question was to reduce/eliminate the bright light coming out of the LCD screen when the vertical polariser filter is removed. Do you reckon there is a way I can make the screen less bright while vertical polariser is removed and by wearing polariser glasses still be able to see what is shown on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

LCD [backlights](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/IPod_Touch_2G_Backlight.JPG) are simple LEDs and it depends on the device if it is adjustable or not. In most cases it is, and it is usually controlled by pulse-width modulation (PWM). Which means that the supply voltage of the LEDs is applied discontinuously, and the longer these pulses the brighter will be the LEDs.

[image]

This happens rapidly so for our eyes it seems continuous in every cases, we only see the LEDs less bright when the pulses are shorter.

The LCD's content is visible and readable without backlight, it only requires ambient light instead.

[image]